# Will a 1-hour 47 minute layover in Fort Lauderdale be enough?

Tags: short-connections, fll, jetblue

I'm booking a trip from Boston to Costa Rica with Jet Blue, and it includes a 1 hour 47 minutes layover at Fort Lauderdale. It's one of the cheaper flights and also gets me earlier to Costa Rica.

Will that be enough time for me to get to my second flight? I have one carry on and one checked bag. I assume Jet Blue will sort out my checked bag, as I'm making the booking under one code, and I'll just pick it up when I'm in Costa Rica.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Ft Lauderdale airport](http://www.fortlauderdaleinternationalairport.com/ft-lauderdale-airport-directions-maps.htm) website, JetBlue uses terminal 1, Concourse C.  Ft Lauderdale is already a small airport, and JetBlue only uses part of one terminal so you will have plenty of time to transit.

[image]

But even that you are booking JetBlue all the way through, they should have already accounted for your transit time and believe that the connection is reasonable.

So don't worry about things and just enjoy Costa Rica.

---

What's weird to me is that I flew JetBlue to Ft Lauderdale several times last year and I would swear I never used Terminal 1